# SAML-Key with alias mykey doesn't have a private key

Tags: ssl, jakarta-ee, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-saml

I am trying to modifying a sample program of spring-boot security with saml.
https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample. I got the certificate(.crt) from my Identity provider and I tried to create a sample keystore(.jks) to test my connectivity before integrating to my application.
I followed below steps to create the certificate.

**Create Key store**

```
keytool -keystore mykeystore.jks -genkey -alias saml
```

When I try to list my keystore I have one private Key

**Listing the Keystore**

```
keytool -list -V -storepass changeit -keystore mykeystore.jks
```

The I imported the certificate provided by the IDP team using below command.

`keytool -import -file myidp.crt -storepass changeit -keystore mykeystore.jks`

Now my when I list my jks file I have two entries one private.

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

Alias name: saml
Creation date: May 24, 2016
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
*******************************************
*******************************************
Alias name: mykey
Creation date: May 24, 2016
Entry type: trustedCertEntry
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
*******************************************
*******************************************
```

I modified the WebSecurityConfi.java class, I did not give any pass phrase while importing the crt to key store. I have tried to keep the alias name as same, but then I was getting below error.

`keytool error: java.lang.Exception: **Public keys in reply and keystore don't match`

```
  @Bean
    public KeyManager keyManager() {
        DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
        Resource storeFile =   loader.getResource("classpath:/saml/myKeystore.jks");

        String storePass = "changeit";
        Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<>();
        passwords.put("changeit", "changeit");
        String defaultKey = "mykey";
        return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, defaultKey);
    }
```

Now I am getting below exception, I know it is some issue with my JKS creation. Could you please suggest how to add private key for my trusted store. I only received the .crt file from IDP provider. Do I have to do any other steps to add the private key for my trusted store? I checked couple of post like [Key with alias xxx doesn't have a private key with Spring SAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950935/key-with-alias-xxx-doesnt-have-a-private-key-with-spring-saml) similar to my issue but I am not able to figure out the issue with certificate creation.

> ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (DirectJDKLog.java:182) - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: **Key with alias mykey doesn't have a private key**
>       at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.getServerKeyInfo(MetadataGenerator.java:209)
>       at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.buildSPSSODescriptor(MetadataGenerator.java:329)
>       at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.generateMetadata(MetadataGenerator.java:189)
>       at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.processMetadataInitialization(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:86)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (DispatcherServlet.java:861) - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
>   DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:318) - Looking up handler method for path /error
>   DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:325) - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
>   DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
>   DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (DispatcherServlet.java:947) - Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
>   DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:225) - Written [{timestamp=Tue May 24 19:12:00 IST 2016, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, exception=java.lang.RuntimeException, message=Key with alias mykey doesn't have a private key, path=/favicon.ico}] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@380682cd]
>   DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (DispatcherServlet.java:1034) - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link between private key and signed certificate in keystore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238337/link-between-private-key-and-signed-certificate-in-keystore)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the signed certificate using the same alias as the private key.

> Now my when I list my jks file I have two entries, one private

You should only have one, private.

Comment: I have tried that,but then I am getting below error. keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match

Comment: Then you have the wrong KeyStore or the wrong alias or the wrong certificate. You started with a keypair, which had an alias; you generated a CSR from the same alias: you obtained a signed certificate from the CSR; then you need to import the signed certificate into the same KeyStore with the same alias.

Answer (score -1):

You can have any number of private key entries in your keystore... but you can configure only one private key to spring saml...  you private key should be of type `Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry`   .. and update your spring-security.xml  to have alias of the private key.   E.g.

```
<!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
            <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
                <constructor-arg value="classpath:keycloak.jks"/>
                <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="password"/>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="YOUR_ALIAS" value="password"/>
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="YOUR_ALIAS"/>
            </bean>
```